# Get Elements By Class Name Nodelist does not apply new styles on every element

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to apply a new class name on each of the list items that have the class "hot"

```
<li class="hot">item</li>
```

I stored a nodelist of these "hot" list-items in a variable called "hotItems"

```
var hotItems = document.getElementsByClassName('hot');
```

and did a for-loop by which every list item would have a new class name called "cool"

```
for(var i = 0; i < hotItems.length; i++){
  hotItems[i].className = 'cool';
}
```

The result I see is that instead of every list-item having the "cool" class name, only every other element has it.

Any reason why the new class name isn't applied on all list items?

I tried accessing the "hoItems" elements with `document.querySelectorAll('.hot')` which worked fine.

Here's a link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/johnnyginbound/pen/WaPYax)

Comment: `hotItems` is a "live NodeList". When you remove the class from an element, it's removed from the list, and all the following indexes shift down.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I got it to work with getElementsByTagName('li') and that's still an HTML collection in the same way that getElementsByClassName('hot') is. The classes applied to all of the elements. I still don't understand this even after looking at your link to the other question. 
appreciate your help!

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('.hot')`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return a *live* collection, it doesn't change when you add and remove classes.

Comment: lastly, can you kindly elaborate on “all the following indexes shift down?” I know the length of the Html collection decreases as the class is removed, but I still fail to see why the next immediate list item wouldn’t get the new “cool” style

Comment: Indexes in the collection are sequential starting from 0. If the element with index 3 leaves the collection, the element with index 4 becomes 3, 5 becomes 4, and so on.